# Internet Explorer 8 starts to download GWT javascript files instead showing them as page after resetting

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-8

Additional Information:
Plarform: Windows 7 Latest Updates, Windows XP Comp View Virtual Machine 
Version: Internet Explorer 8.0.7601.17514

I am developing a gwt application and recently get this problem:
With fresh installation of Windows 7 and ie8 everything works fine, but after resetting all the configuration data, ie8 starts to prompt dialog for downloading javascript files instead rendering them in page. It is more interesting that this does not occurs every time, but on some machines looks fine after resetting, on others is disaster. Looks like some kind of specific Windows configuration, because if it happens with Windows 7, it happens too with the compatibility mode for Windows XP.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to Internet Options
2. Go to General Tab -> Click on Delete browsing history on exit -> Click on Delete button
3. Go to Security Tab -> Click on Reset all zones to default level
4. Go to Advanced Tab -> Restore advanced settings
5. Go to Advanced Tab -> Click on Reset Button -> Click on Delete Personal Settings Checkbox -> Click on Reset Button
6. Restart Internet Explorer 8 and try to start gwt application

Thank you for the answers in advance.

P.S. Can try to reproduce the problem with: http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the unknown content type of the files.

Try to add:

```
<mime-mapping>    
    <extension>js</extension>        
    <mime-type>application/x-javascript</mime-type>        
</mime-mapping>
```

to you web.xml

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for the answer. But the solution doesn't work. It is still trying to download the "cache.html" permutation file.